# File admin script both Linux and Windows compatible

Tags: ruby, linux, windows, file

I've written a command-line application that allows me to copy certain files to and from the Desktop. And up until now it's been fine since I was on Ubuntu, but now I'm adding a Windows 7 machine that doesn't play well with my current implementation.

My current solution is to duplicate my scripts and hard code paths.

```
CANVAS_DIR = "#{HOME}/GitHub/canvas"
```

gets replaced with:

```
CANVAS_DIR = "C:\\Users\\wurde\\GitHub\\canvas"
```

I've read that I should avoid hard coding paths and instead use joins. Is that the best way? If so, how does that look implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the File API in Ruby I think I have the a working `join` solution. The important bit was to include the home directory via environment variable.

```
CANVAS_DIR = File.join(ENV['HOME'], 'GitHub', 'canvas')
```